# Is Vue.JS, React or Angular cross-platform?

Tags: javascript, cross-platform, javascript-framework

After reading many articles, comparing Vue.JS vs React vs Angular vs jQuery, I came across articles that say jQuery is cross-platform.

Is Vue.JS, React or Angular also cross-platform? I could not find any articles saying about this. Thus, maybe these are not cross-platform.

I do understand What cross-platform means in general but what does cross-platform mean in the term of a Javascript Framework/Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-platform means, that you can create an application which gonna look nice and work responsively on any type of device (desktop, phone, tablet, etc.).

As you mentioned JQuery is cross-platform, but not by default. You have to use [JQuery mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/) framework to achieve it.
The same solution is possible with React.js and Vue.js. For react you can use [React-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) framework, for Vue there is [Vue Native](https://vue-native.io/).

So yes, all of these frameworks are cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is rather cross browser than cross platform.

It means that jQuery method can have different implementation for different browsers. And it means that every jQuery method is highly optimized for each browser (like Chrome, IE, Safari etc).

In 2009 when jQuery was created it was critical feature. Together with intuitive and elegant syntax cross browser compatibility made jQuery what it is today - the most popular JavaScript library of all times.

Today in 2019 cross browser compatibility is not a big issue anymore. But still jQuery is very relevant.

Rewrite below code in pure JavaScript and you will understand.

```
$('#outerDiv').find($('.smallDiv')).find($('.play')).each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('gray').addClass('black').click(function(){
        play(); 
    });
});
```

Angular, React and other trendy frameworks was not optimized for different browsers. This means, that same application can behave differently in Chrome and IE11.